# Can I enlarge the system scrollbar size?

Tags: window-manager, system-settings

I would like to enlarge/widen the default system scrollbar size - it annoys me how the width has shrunk over the years. I have found how to do this for certain individual applications (*e.g.* Firefox), but not in general. TIA for any pointers.

Comment: Can you reveal how you managed to do this in Firefox and other apps? (And what OS you're on.) I don't know of any options in Xcode for setting the size of scroll bars when creating an app, so I doubt there are any user-facing parameters. Can I ask why you want them larger? You shouldn't need to drag scroll bars themselves to scroll: scrolling is achieved most easily with the input device itself, e.g. Trackpad or mouse. Scrollbars are mostly "informative" only.

Comment: @benwiggy In Firefox, in about:config, I modified `widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size.override` (sb width) and `widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.style` (I like style **4**) and apparently `layout.css.scrollbar-width-thin.disabled = true` is useful too. (That's the only app I've done it on so far.) I do respect that you consider scrollbars mostly "informative;" I use them for much more than that. IMO it's the best tool for grabbing with my mouse to quickly scrub through a web page. As mentioned, I find the default size too thin; it takes unneeded effort on my part to grab it.

Comment: That's definitely a unique feature to Firefox. What kind of mouse do you have? It's objectively much slower to move the pointer to the scrollbar and drag that control, than to just move a scroll wheel on the mouse, or use a gesture on a trackpad, wherever the pointer is in the window. Or just press Page Down. Apple has 'deprecated' the need for manual dragging of scrollbars since 2010. I know "Don't do that" isn't the answer you want.